# How to structure a Dart application with multiple views with Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

This question has been asked before but since the answer to that question Dart has adopted polymer to replace Web UI.  Is there a Polymer version of the answer to this question?  Also, I saw the answer relating to routes, which I like, but investigating it further has led me to believe that routes and polymer do not play well together yet.

I would also like to solicit views on the new Angular-Dart since I am comfortable with Angular but see it as a competing technology to polymer at least in the Dart world.

[How to build a complex Web UI application with multiple views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188370/how-to-build-a-complex-web-ui-application-with-multiple-views)

Comment: Since Polymer is just a later version of web_ui (Polymer >= 0.5.0, web_ui is  < 0.5.0) of the same framework, I believe the responses in the original question are still valid, only the syntax and API changes need be updated (ie, new Element.tag() vs new Element.html() etc). See my sample on using routes here: https://github.com/butlermatt/routes_example

Comment: @Matt B, I read through your example.  Nice job. Please post this as the answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Polymer is just a later version of web_ui (Polymer >= 0.5.0, web_ui is < 0.5.0) of the same framework, I believe the responses in the original question are still valid, only the syntax and API changes need be updated (ie, new Element.tag() vs new Element.html() etc).

See my sample on using [routes with polymer](http://github.com/butlermatt/routes_example)