# Set the dart-editor server responses

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dart-pub

My apache server is setup to respond to any request with the index.html. The idea behind this is to let the web app we are creating handle the routing. The dart-editor test environment does not do this by default.

Instead when i go to `http://127.0.0.1.8080/something/that/does/not/exisit` it will return a 404. I would like it to respond with the index.html and let the app handle the routing.

Is it possible to setup this behaviour for the dart test environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested way is to use a custom server that acts as a proxy that forwards to `pub serve`.

see also

- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20432

The code (copied from the linked issue)

```dart
Future proxyToPub(HttpRequest request, String path) {
    const RESPONSE_HEADERS = const [
        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH,
        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE ];

    var uri = pubServeUrl.resolve(path);
    return client.openUrl(request.method, uri)
        .then((proxyRequest) {
          proxyRequest.headers.removeAll(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING);
          return proxyRequest.close();
        })
        .then((proxyResponse) {
          proxyResponse.headers.forEach((name, values) {
            if (RESPONSE_HEADERS.contains(name)) {
              request.response.headers.set(name, values);
            }
          });
          request.response.statusCode = proxyResponse.statusCode;
          request.response.reasonPhrase = proxyResponse.reasonPhrase;
          return proxyResponse.pipe(request.response);
        })
        .catchError((e) {
          print("Unable to connect to 'pub serve' for '${request.uri}': $e");
          var error = new AssetError(
              "Unable to connect to 'pub serve' for '${request.uri}': $e");
          return new Future.error(error);
        });
  }
```

I use the `route_hierarchical` package in a way that it works the same with `usePushState` enabled or disabled. This way I can use URL fragments for development and pushState for deployment.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25256858/217408 
or the two similar (simple) examples where one uses `usePushState` `false` and the other `true` https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_polymer_routing

Comment: The import 'dart:html' is not available on the stand-alone VM. So i cannot run this in the dart-editor

Comment: This should become a console application that is run individually from your application you are currently developing. The imports are probably `dart:io` and maybe `dart.http`. You launch your entry page using DartEditor with a custom launch configuration that points to this proxy. (I haven't used this myself yet)